# Convert time to string format based on iPhone settings (13:00 vs 1:00PM) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp, nsdate

I currently have a integer variable for the hour of a current day, I calculated it like this:

```
let tz = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
let now = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().componentsInTimeZone(tz, fromDate: NSDate())
let currHour: Int = now.hour //6 for 6:35PM (current time)
```

How do I convert this to a string given the iPhone's current time settings. For example, my phone is set to 24-hour times while another iPhone is not. Using the Starbucks app as an example, looking at local stores, it will say either "Open until 22:00" on my phone or "Open until 10:00PM" on the other phone.

The defaultTimeZone is set to America/New_York in the app delegate.

Comment: Have you tried `NSDateFormatter`? It does all of this for you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html

Comment: NSDate is locale agnostic. It ensures that two date objects that represent the same time/date will always be equatable, even under different locales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` does this automatically. Just set the `timeStyle` to `.ShortStyle`.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

The value for `timeString` will be appropriate for the user's locale and their device settings.

Comment: It worked great. To create an NSDate() I used the NSDate(fromTimeInterval) and then used the code that you provided to return a string. Thank you so much!